# Secure boot disable but xubuntu 18.04 usb shows in EUFI

Tags: boot, xubuntu, 18.04, grub-legacy

I downloaded and made a bootable usb using Rufus and xubuntu 18.04. I have already windows installed. I have secure boot disabled in bios and legacy boot enabled. However i make tre partiotions when installing. One ext4 70GB. 3GB for Swap and 300 for Efi/boot. However when the installation is done and i boot the system up the content of image is appeared. [image]

I tried to make the partitions in gparted and same thing. I tried to fix the grub using grub-repair and the error i get was something like "the boot partition is far away from the start of disk. Move it and make a ext4 bigger than 300mB" i did that too and removed all partition and made a clean installation and still i see the same image.

It is a hp probook 650 g2.

Comment: What happens if you let the installer do the partitioning (use one of the guided alternatives)? Will it create a working system?

Comment: With UEFI & gpt, the far from start of drive issue is not valid, that is for older BIOS systems still using IDE. HP is not dual boot friendly. But can you boot Ubuntu entry from UEFI boot menu or boot0012. Post link for Summary Report from Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info